# Script Editor no longer asks for TouchID when running Apple Script with Admin Privileges

Tags: applescript, touch-id

When running an AppleScript like

`do shell script "sudo echo 'Hello'" with administrator privileges`

I always have to enter my password and can't use TouchID.

I already edited pam.d/sudo and sudo_local to add

`auth sufficient pam_tid.so`

And while running the command directly from the Terminal does let me use TouchID, running it from Script Editor forces me to use my password.

The problem appeared with Sonoma. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ultimately, I found out that if I run the same terminal command from Shortcuts, it triggers TouchID. So in a nutshell, it looks like Script Editor is done for, and it's really time to switch to Shortcuts.